# Как создать калькулятор в JavaScript при помощи function и switch case?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
let num1 = prompt('первое число');
num1 = Number(num1);

let num2 = prompt('второе число');
num2 = Number(num2);


let operator = prompt('оператор (/,+,*,-)');


switch (operator) {
    case '+':
        alert (num1 + num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        alert (num1 - num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        alert (num1 / num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        alert (num1 * num2);
        
     
}
```

Как заменить конструкции в `case` на `return`?

**UPD**

Требуется использовать присвоение переменной в `case` и потом вернуть значение.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const calc = (num1, num2, operator) => {
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return num1 + num2;
        case '-':
            return num1 - num2;
        case '/':
            return num1 / num2;
        case '*':
            return num1 * num2;
    }
};

console.log(calc(1, 2, '+'));
console.log(calc(5, 7, '*'));
```

Comment: Да, только return лучше сделать один в конце.А в кейсах записывай результат в переменную (которую в итоге будет возвращать return).Затем идёт вызов этой функции.В качестве параметров передавай данные, которые ты получил от пользователя

Comment: @НикитаМанакин ну, лучше - сделайте)

Comment: Знал бы как, сделал бы. Я уже торчу 6 часов над эти калькулятором

Comment: Ой да ладно, вы в комментарии уже описали то, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Так это преподаватель написал, я скинул ему ваш код и он сказал что нужно переделать

Comment: @НикитаМанакин ну вот и переделайте. Там написано то, что нужно сделать. Это уровень даже не то что базовый, а сверхбазовый.

Comment: Раз это сверхбазовый уровень, то дайте ответ

Comment: @НикитаМанакин а вы знаете как создать переменную и присвоить ей значение?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper знаю.

Comment: @НикитаМанакин отлично, значит вы можете в начале функции объявить переменную и в switch вместо `return` записывать результат в переменную, так?

Comment: Так я пробовал, только ничего не получается

Comment: @НикитаМанакин покажи как пробовал. Не получается - понятие абстрактное

Comment: let num1 = prompt('первое число');
num1 = Number(num1);

let num2 = prompt('второе число');
num2 = Number(num2);

let operator = prompt('оператор (/,+,*,-)');

function calc(num1, num2, operator)  {
    switch (operator) {
        case '-':
            result = num2 - num1;
            break;
        case '+':
            result = num2 + num1;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = num2 * num1;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = num2 / num1;
            break;
    }
        return alert(result);
};

Comment: @НикитаМанакин так, отлично. Только `result` надо бы объявить в начале функции........а возвращать в конце не alert, а сам `result`. ну и не забыть вызывать эту самую функцию с нужными параметрами

Answer (score -1):

```
let num1 = prompt('первое число');
num1 = Number(num1);

let num2 = prompt('второе число');
num2 = Number(num2);

let operator = prompt('оператор (/,+,*,-)');

function calc(num1, num2, operator)  {

switch (operator) {
   
  case '-':
       
    result = num2 - num1;
      
   break;
   
  case '+':
     
    result = num2 + num1;
      
   break;
   
 case '*':
       
   result = num2 * num1;
     
  break;
  
 case '/':
    
   result = num2 / num1;
     
  break;
   
 default:
       
 alert("Такого оператора не существует");
}
   
 return alert(result);
};
```